# Change dll output in a project using visual studio 2010 express

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In VS 2010 express there are a few library projects (dlls) attached to the application project. When building the solution the dlls output to bin/Release/. Is there a way to have the .exe output to bin/Release and the dlls to bin/Release/dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires either a .config file with the `<probing>` element or implementing AppDomain.AssemblyResolve so that the CLR can find these DLLs.  You'll have a deployment problem too, you have to convince ClickOnce to publish these DLLs.  Realistically should only attempt this with the retail edition of Visual Studio so you can create a Setup project.

Fwiw: your customer won't mind that the DLLs are in the same folder as the EXE.  I think most actually strongly prefer this.  I do.

Answer (score 0):

You could always have a [post build event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx) on the application project that copies all `.dll` files to a `dll` directory.

However the assembly loader will not be able to find the `dll` file and you application will not start.